# Can ILogger be trusted to catch / log ALL uncaught exceptions?

Tags: asp.net-core

Title asks it all.

Is there ever, and if so when, would `ILogger` not log an uncaught exception?

Reason I am asking is; am configuring Rollbar and it logs everything `ILogger` logs plus uncaught exceptions.  This creates 2 logs.  I am considering disabling Rollbar's log uncaught exceptions with the belief that `ILogger` catches them all already.

This question isn't about Rollbar tho :)

Comment: It *should*. However, `ILogger` doesn't do anything on its own. As such, it's up to the individual pieces of the application, both framework and custom code to log what they want logged.

Comment: Sure, except if the error occurred with `ILogger` while trying to log an entry. Other than that, I second what Chris Pratt said.

Comment: From an asp.net-core perspective, a middleware early in the pipeline should be able to catch all uncaught error as it bubbles back upstream.

Comment: My own observation is, the first line of `Program.main` logs. I believe all is caught, but if I have a definitive answer, I can share with with Rollbar for this [issue](https://github.com/rollbar/Rollbar.NET/issues/346#issuecomment-506088298).  Rollbar is logging uncaught exceptions twice, and their Dev made the following statement I wanted to validate: "catching of exceptions and reporting them via the ILogger is not guaranteed by any codebase, in general. "

Comment: This is a combination of the following two topics [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) and [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I have read and am familiar with both those links.  I believe neither of them answer question.

Comment: So far reviewing their source on GitHub does not reveal anything out of the ordinary. They have a custom middleware and provider  added like any other https://github.com/rollbar/Rollbar.NET/blob/master/Rollbar.NetCore.AspNet/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

No. [`ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) is an interface. It doesn't do anything. Rather, implementations of `ILogger` should log uncaught exceptions. It sounds like Rollbar is already doing your logging so you should continue to use that for logging your uncaught exceptions, or switch to a different library like NLog, Serilog, or log4net.

Personally, I have found that some libraries do miss messages in different cases, so it's important to test your logging library. It's not enough to just have faith that the messages are being correctly written. You can write unit tests to make sure that your code is logging exceptions correctly with Moq. Here is an example from [this article](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/07/03/ilogger/).

```
_loggerMock.Verify
(
    l => l.Log
    (
        //Check the severity level
        LogLevel.Error,
        //This may or may not be relevant to your scenario
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        //This is the magical Moq code that exposes internal log processing from the extension methods
        It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((state, t) =>
            //This confirms that the correct log message was sent to the logger. {OriginalFormat} should match the value passed to the logger
            //Note: messages should be retrieved from a service that will probably store the strings in a resource file
            CheckValue(state, LogTest.ErrorMessage, "{OriginalFormat}") &&
            //This confirms that an argument with a key of "recordId" was sent with the correct value
            //In Application Insights, this will turn up in Custom Dimensions
            CheckValue(state, recordId, nameof(recordId))
    ),
    //Confirm the exception type
    It.IsAny<NotImplementedException>(),
    //Accept any valid Func here. The Func is specified by the extension methods
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),
    //Make sure the message was logged the correct number of times
    Times.Exactly(1)
);
```

But, even this doesn't guarantee that Rollbar or some other logger will definitely get your message to the log location. You can only confirm this by observing the output of the logger.

You should also see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-logging) of the `ILogger` documentation which explains how to configure logging and potentially filter them.